# Backup job doesn't write backup when run on schedule

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup

We have a database that is backed up to a network drive by a job scheduled to run at 7 AM everyday. The issue is the backup doesn't get created; however, when I execute the job manually, it gets created just fine.

It's not like the scheduled job fails either. If I look at the job history, it indicates that the job ran fine and the backup database operation succeeded.

I don't think it's a permissions issue writing to that folder either since all the other backup jobs also execute using the same user and they run just fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the command the job is executing? Have you ran the command outside of the job to see if it executes?

Answer (score 1):

Does anything show up in the backupset tables for the missing backups?

```
SELECT  TOP 5
        bs.database_name, 
        bmf.physical_device_name,
        bs.backup_finish_date,
        BackupSize = CONVERT( VARCHAR( 16 ), 
            CONVERT( DECIMAL( 18, 4 ), bs.backup_size * 1.0 / 1024 ) ) + 'KB',
        AfterCompression = CONVERT( VARCHAR( 16 ), 
            CONVERT( DECIMAL( 18, 4 ), bs.compressed_backup_size * 1.0 / 1024 ) ) + 'KB',
        bs.type
FROM    msdb.dbo.backupset bs
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily bmf
    ON  bmf.media_set_id = bs.media_set_id
WHERE   bs.database_name = '<Your Catalog Here>'
    AND bs.type = 'D'
ORDER BY bs.backup_finish_date DESC;
```

I would wager you are right that it's not a permissions issue, as if it was, the job history would indicate it.  Similarly, if the network path was simply unavailable at 7:00AM, there'd be something in the job messages about it, even if the jobstep itself was set to always report success.

```
SELECT  ji.name, ji.step_name, ji.step_id, ji.run_date, 
        ji.run_time, ji.run_status, ji.on_success_action, ji.on_fail_action, ji.message
FROM (  SELECT  sj.name, sjs.step_name, sjs.step_id, sjh.run_date, sjh.run_time,
                sjh.run_status, sjh.message, sjs.on_success_action, sjs.on_fail_action,
                Ordinal = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY sj.name
                    ORDER BY sjh.run_date DESC, sjh.run_time DESC )
        FROM    msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj
        INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps sjs
            ON  sjs.job_id = sj.job_id
        INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory sjh
            ON  sjh.job_id = sj.job_id
            AND sjh.step_id = sjs.step_id ) ji
WHERE   ji.Ordinal <= 5
    AND ji.name = '<Your Job Here>'
ORDER BY ji.run_date DESC, ji.run_time DESC,
    ji.name, ji.step_id;
```

I'm guessing it's some subtle difference between the successful jobs and the one that's behaving oddly, like a conditional that's getting evaluated differently by the agent or similar code issue.

Comment: So running the first query does indeed show records for the db in question, both for my manual attempt and the one that ran on schedule. 

The second query doesn't seem to indicate any differences in any of the conditions that it looks at. All the values are similar whether running manually or through the schedule.

Comment: If the first query is showing the expected phys_dev path with reasonable finish date / size attributes, I don't think there's anything else I can offer to help you :(  If those were my backups, I'd just try pointing to a different place for now, as I'd pretty much be convinced something is coming along and moving / deleting them after completion.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate your help! I'm going to change the time of the backup to sometime where I can observe it and see if what you're saying is right: it's getting created then deleted for whatever reason.